# Why do I get "uninitialized constant" when calling a Controller action in a daemon script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to daemonize an action in my controller. In the rails console the action works as expected, I can run `VsensorsController.update_vsensors` but when I call this action in my daemon script it fails with `uninitialized constant (NameError)`. I've tried using `include`, and `require` with no success. What is the proper way to call this action from a daemon script?

Script to start daemons in `script/daemon`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

ENV['APP_ROOT'] ||= File.expand_path("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/..")
ENV['RAILS_ENV_PATH'] ||= "#{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/config/environment.rb"

script = "#{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/daemons/#{ARGV[1]}"

Daemons.run(script, dir_mode: :normal, dir: "#{ENV['APP_ROOT']}/tmp/pids")
```

Damon Script in `daemons` directory (this is where it's failing):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

# You might want to change this
#ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'

$running = true
Signal.trap('TERM') do
  $running = false
end

while $running do

  loop do
    sleep 10
    VsensorsController.update_vsensors
  end

end
```

Controller:

```
class VsensorsController < ApplicationController

  def self.update_vsensors
    vs_services = Array.new
    if Vsensor.count > 0
      hosts = Vsensor.all
      hosts.each do |host|
        sys_host_id = host.sys_host_id
        sys_host = SysHost.find(sys_host_id)
        user_id = sys_host.user_id
        creds = User.find(user_id)
        session = Net::SSH.start(host.ip.to_s, creds.username, :password => creds.password,
                                 :encryption => 'aes256-cbc', :host_key => 'ssh-rsa')
        vsensor_commands = Net::SSH::Telnet.new('Session' => session)
        stat_rules = vsensor_commands.cmd('stat /etc/snort/rules/snort.rules')
        sig_change = stat_rules.scan(/Change:\s+\d+-\d+-\d+/).to_s
        sig_update = sig_change.scan(/\d+-\d+-\d+/)
        snort_services = vsensor_commands.cmd("ps -ef | grep s\\nort | grep -Ev 'barnyard' | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d\" \" -f 18 | cut -d\"/\" -f 4 | cut -d\".\" -f 1")
        snort_svs = snort_services.scan(/[S|s][N|n][O|o][R|r][T|t]\d+/)

        barnyard2_services = vsensor_commands.cmd("ps -ef | grep b\\arnyard | sed 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d\" \" -f 11 | cut -d\"/\" -f 4 | cut -d\".\" -f 1,2")
        by2_svs = barnyard2_services.scan(/[B|b][A|a][R|r][N|n][Y|y][A|a][R|r][D|d]2.\w+/)

        vs_services << snort_svs
        vs_services << by2_svs
        host.update_attributes(sig_updated_at: sig_update[0], running_services: vs_services)
        session.close
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: you can use `/i` for case insensitivity - `/snort\d+/i` instead of `/[S|s][N|n][O|o][R|r][T|t]\d+/`

Comment: Ok thanks.That will clean up that part some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Daemons before, so I have no idea how deep is its integration, if any, with rails. My guess is none.

Given that, you need to `require` the files to make them available to your script. Like you said, you've tried it, but be aware you have to require **all** of the dependencies, i.e. yours models, application_controller, etc.; not only the `VsensorsController`.

That's the reason it works in the `rails console` and not in your script. Because in the former, the rails environment is fully loaded.

I think the easiest way to achieve this is using a rake task inherited from `environment`, so your script will behave like the console, with all dependencies loaded.